# Different color points in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following R-code,

```
x1=c(3,2,4,1,2,4,4)
x2=c(4,2,4,4,1,3,1)
Y=c("red","red","red","red","blue","blue","blue")
plot(x1,x2,col=Y,pch=8)
grid(NULL,NULL,col="cornsilk2")
legend("right",c("Point","star"),col=c("red","blue"))
```

That creates a plot as seen below
[image: Test image]

There are two things that I wish to change however I am not sure how to go about it. 
1) I want to change the types of points that appear using the pch feature in plot. So for example, I want the red points to appear as a star and the blue points to appear as a triangle. How would I go about this?
2) I want the legend to show those symbols and be coloured respectively correctly. For example, instead of having "Point" it should be a "." that is coloured blue or red depending on what colour I decide to assign it.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `plot`).

Comment: Alright, sorry for that. This is part of a machine-learning build up but once it gets to that part if I have questions I'll make sure to note them properly.

Comment: No problem, just keep it in mind for the future, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify a vector like your color:

```
SHAPE = ifelse(Y=="red",8,2)
plot(x1,x2,col=Y,pch=SHAPE)
legend("right",c("Point","star"),col=c("blue","red"),pch=c(2,8))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this takes care of it. I wasn't aware that the pch function would handle separate identified variables.